# LinearSVC modiffy coef_ for federated

Tags: linear-regression, svm, libsvm

i want to combine several Linearsvc making an average of feature importance (coef_) and to train using the coef initialized.

but i found that coef_ for the linearsvc is not writeable only readable.

Is there any way to update the coefs as in logistic regression?

Thanks

Comment: I have used  SGDClassifier that implements Linear svc with gradient descent and it allows me to do that, but very bad results compared with LinearSVC. Any idea why?